# conditional statement is not working in html file

Tags: html

I am trying to execute if condition in html file and tried below code but this code gives output with all the lines

```
{% ifequal selected_choice 'Yellow' %} 
    <p> you entered correct </p>
   {% endifequal %}
```

Comment: Umm you can't do conditionals in html. Are you running a php file file?

Comment: Are you working Django ??

Answer (score 0):

change attr to "input" or whatever you gave in the code previously

```
{% if attr == "yellow" %} 
   <p> you entered correct </p>
{% else %}

<!!- {% endif %} optional one -->
```

try to write it similar way